# Displaying 3D text in real world using Augmented Reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia

ARKit provides a framework to display 3D text in real world using augmented reality. This  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzEevVPWijM) explains the same:

Is there a similar mechanism to do the same using Unity and Vuforia augmented reality support??

I tried displaying 3D text, but it simply gets rendered as a 2D text.

Comment: Mesh Text is 2D text that exists in 3D space, it's not 3D-modeled text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the standard UI Text component. Use [`BaseMeshEffect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.BaseMeshEffect.html) to obtain the Mesh and vertices of the Text component then extrude it outwards. You now how have a 3D Object. You may need to change the material to standard material.

---

If you can't implement this then use an existing plugin. The [Simple Helvetica](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/simple-helvetica-2925) plugin can do this and it's free on the assetstore.